# How to have a run in an Service?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I have implemented an service that runs in a seperate process.

This service contains a separate thread where i have a socket connection.
This thread has a run() where it is continuously sending data to the port.

My problem is after triggering the run() in the thread i don't get any contact with it anymore, i can see in the program that have open the socket that it consciously sends the data but the idea was that i while it is running i could change data that it sends for an example time.

here is my run in the external thread:

```
public void run()
{

        if(run) 
            {

            // Team and player names message is sent when entering in a game

            setBaseMessage();
            SendMessageToCOMPort(base_message + CalculateCRC(base_message));
            sleep();  // waits for 100 ms
           }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what might be wrong ?

Comment: Well i found another way now, instead of having a run im now using a timer and timer task.

Comment: If you have found another way, you could post a detailed answer by yourself.

Comment: have to low points so cant really post an answer, sorry.

But i used a timer task like this istead:
`code`
 private TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
   setNamesTeamsPlayerMessage();
   setBaseMessage();
   SendMessageToCOMPort(base_message +   CalculateCRC(base_message));
   sleep();
`code`

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite get your problem. It seems that you want to run a separate thread in your service which does some socket communication. Furthermore you want to be able to influence the data the thread is sending using the socket.

> I have implemented an service that runs in a seperate process.

First of all, android services aren't running in a separate process or thread by default. Therefore, to run long running operations you have to develop multithreading by your self using Java threading and implementing the run method as you have done it.

Threads of a single process share the same memory. Therefore, to influence what the socket thread is doing, you can use data structures like a queue or a list which are shared among the threads. For example, you could apply the producer-consumer pattern. The producer passes data to a shared queue. The consumer consumes the data from the queue and processes it. However, be aware that you have to synchronize the access to the shared queue.

I hope I was able to clarify the issue and give you some advice to solve the issue.